# Having trouble with datatable invalid JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I keep having this error. I manage to track down the response by inspecting the dataTable which lead me to believe that this is the source of the problem. Please bear with me for I'm still a beginner in javascript and PHP.

image link to error:
[source of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYze8.png)

here are my codes:

config.php

```
<?php
class dbConfig {
    protected $serverName;
    protected $userName;
    protected $password;
    protected $dbName;
    function dbConfig() {
        $this -> serverName = 'localhost';
        $this -> userName = 'root';
        $this -> password = '';
        $this -> dbName = 'database';
    }
}
?>
```

user.php

```
<?php
require('config.php');
class User extends dbconfig {
    protected $hostName;
    protected $userName;
    protected $password;
    protected $dbName;
    private $userTable = 'user';
    private $dbConnect = false;
    public function __construct(){
        if(!$this->dbConnect){
            $database = new dbConfig();
            $this -> hostName = $database -> serverName;
            $this -> userName = $database -> userName;
            $this -> password = $database -> password;
            $this -> dbName = $database -> dbName;
            $conn = new mysqli($this->hostName, $this->userName, $this->password, $this->dbName);
            if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Error failed to connect to MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } else{
                $this->dbConnect = $conn;
            }
        }
    }
    private function getData($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $query);
        if(!$result){
            die('Error in query: '. mysqli_error());
        }
        $data= array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    private function getNumRows($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $query);
        if(!$result){
            die('Error in query: '. mysqli_error());
        }
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $numRows;
    }
    public function userList(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->userTable." ";
        if(!empty($_POST["search"]["value"])){
            $query .= 'where(user_id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $query .= ' OR user_fname LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $query .= ' OR user_mname LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $query .= ' OR user_lname LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $query .= ' OR user_address LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $query .= ' OR user_contactnumber LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $query .= ' OR user_birthdate LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%") ';
        }
        if(!empty($_POST["order"])){
            $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
        } else {
            $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
        }
        if($_POST["length"] != -1){
            $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $query);
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $userData = array();
        while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $userRows = array();
                $userRows[] = $user['user_id'];
                $userRows[] = ucfirst($user['user_fname']);
                $userRows[] = $user['user_mname'];
                $userRows[] = $user['user_lname'];
                $userRows[] = $user['user_address'];
                $userRows[] = $user['user_contactnumber'];
                $userRows[] = $user['user_birthdate'];
                $userRows[] = '>button type="button" name="update" id="'.$user['user_id'].'"class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update"<Update>/button<';
                $userRows[] = '>button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$user['user_id'].'"class="btn btn-danger btn-xs update"<Delete>/button<';
                $userData[] = $userRows;
        }
        $output = array(
        "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
        "recordsTotal"      =>  $numRows,
        "recordsFiltered"   =>  $numRows,
        "data"              =>  $userData
    );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
}

 ?>
```

ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var userRecords = $('#userList').DataTable({
            "lengthChange": false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order":[],
            "ajax":{
                    url:"process.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {action: 'listUser'},
                    dataType: "json"
            },
            "columnDefs":[
                    {
                        "targets": [0, 6, 7],
                        "orderable": false,
                    },
            ],
            "pageLength": 10
    });
});
```

process.php

```
<?php
include('user.php');
$user = new User();
if (!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'listUser') {
    $user -> userList();
}

?>
```

Comment: There is some error in your Query. Using ``mysqli_error($this->dbConnect)``, check for potential errros/warnings.

Comment: Not related, what are `>button` or `update"<Update>/button<` supposed to do?

Comment: @NotABot ok, I'll test it out later

Comment: @kerbh0lz creates a button update

Comment: Well it doesn't, got your `<` and `>` mixed up

Comment: @NotABot after several hours and testing using that function, the problem still persist :(

Comment: @FayedMauyag What does ``mysqli_error($this->dbConnect)`` shows you?

Comment: @NotABot the same error as  this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYze8.png